# What's the algorithm behind this?

Tags: java, algorithm

I got this exercise, but can't figure out the algorithm behind it:

You have a car which drives at speed n (meaning n meters per second) on default. You take the shortest route home (which you already know), but come past some traffic lights. Each traffic light T has a period p which means the traffic light turns on after each p seconds. (*e.g. With a period of 3, the light will be green at time 3, 6, 9, 12, etc. and red at 1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, etc.*) There is also a distance between all the traffic lights, which is denoted by d.

For example: The car constantly drives 1 meter per second. The first traffic light is at a distance of 5. Its period is 3. Meaning that you arrive there at time = 5 and have to wait 1 second before the light turns green. You return your trip at time = 6.

Now there is one more thing: you can also use your turbo with speed m (which will always be bigger or equal to n), but only x times. *The turbo will remain the whole distance between two traffic lights. So in the example it will remain at either 5 or 20 and result into the duration of 2.5 or 10 seconds.*

You have to return the shortest time you can spend from your location to your house. The input will be:
The number of traffic lights | the amount of times you can use your turbo (x) | the normal speed (n) | the turbo speed (m)
Distance to traffic light 1 (Td) | Period of traffic light 1 (Tp)
Distance to traffic light 2 (Td) | Period of traffic light 2 (Tp) 
etc.

So for example:
2 1 1 2
5 3
20 2

Which would give the shortest time of 16. (*The time starts when the car departures and ends when it finishes.*)

What would be the algorithm behind this? Do you have to check every possible time you can run?

I hope you can help me.

**Edit**
I have a way of calculating the time without the option to use turbo:
For each traffic light, I create a Pair(int length, int period). The time is set to 0 on default. The calculation between traffic lights would be:

```
int i = 0;
int time = 0;
while(i<S.size()-1) {
   Pair current = S.get(i);
   time = time + Math.ceil(current.getLength() / n);
   time = current.getPeriod * ceil(time / current.getPeriod());
   i++;
}
return time;
```

But there must be a way to find when to use the turbo or not?

Comment: So.... What have you tried...?

Comment: This is homework, at least try to write some code for it, and come back for advice.

Comment: if I understand it correctly, it seems to be the question where to use the turbo. If you have p traffic lights, you have (p + 1) pieces of road. if you have q boosts, you have p +1 over q possible scenarios. One possibility is to try them all. That would be a good start to learn to know the problem. Afterwards you can try to find optimisations.

Comment: @William-H-M I tried to find a characteristic of when to run, but it seems to be too random. Of course with the example it is obvious that you just take the one with the biggest distance.

Comment: @Ronald Yes, I also thought you just have to try every possibility, but then I'm stuck. How do you do this? As one always depends on the previous calculations

Comment: Are the traffic light identical? i.e. same period and synchronized? Does a period of 3 mean that it is red for 3 epochs, and then green for the next 3 etc?

Comment: @Oli No, as you can see in the example the first traffic light has a distance of 5 and period of 3 and the second one a distance of 20 and period of 2. A period means that it is only green on a multiple of that number. (So with 3 it is green at 3, 6, 9, 12, etc. and red at 1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10, 11, 13, etc.)

Comment: You can just imagine you use the boost on the for instance 3rd and 5th part and then calculate how long you'd need. Now you do this for all other possibilities too and you'll find a minimum. It is not guaranteed that using the boost on the longest part (the advantage might be eaten by the traffic light) is always the best choice.

Comment: Does each of the lights start its cycle at the same time as car starts moving?

Comment: @Ronald Yes, when you can use your turbo once or twice, this is easily implemented. But when you have over 100 traffic lights and can use your turbo 50 times, how will you even go through all the different kinds of sets?

Comment: @yegodm Yes, they start when the car starts at the very start. So for the example above, the car starts 0. The distance is 5, so it arrives at the traffic light at time = 5. The traffic light also has time = 5, but a period of 3 so turns green at 3. The car continues at time = 6. It then has to go to the next traffic light with distance 20, so it arrives there at time = 26. For that traffic light, the time is also 6. The period is 2, so it is green already. (And this example was without using the turbo)

Comment: Seems one more piece is missing - when turbo is activated, for how long does it stay like that - for a specific interval, until the next red light, or until the route is finished?

Comment: @yegodm Oh, indeed forgot to mention that. The turbo will stay on the whole way between the traffic lights. Meaning that with the example above, you can use turbo on 5: time arriving at the traffic light would be 3 (ceil(5/2), as the turbo is 2), you could immediately go on because the traffic light is green and then you arrive at the next one at 23 and have to wait one second.
With the turbo at 20: You take 6 seconds for the first traffic light. 16 seconds to arrive at the next (the 6 seconds + ceil(20/2)) and then the traffic light is green, as its period is 2.

Comment: I would probably start with very dumb brute force simulation first just to generate more test cases. I just wonder if we can assume that every event occurs at a discrete moment represent by the whole number of seconds. If this is correct then every second gives us a few possible outcomes - without or with turbo (provided there are spare turbo shots).

Comment: @yegodm If I understand your question correct, then yes. The time starts ticking when the car starts from the very start and the time will not stop until the car gets home. So if every traffic light has a period of 1 and the distances are 5, 20, 12, then the time at the finish will be 37. The time never stops between two sequences/events and will indeed always be a whole number, as the period of a traffic light will be bigger or equal to 1.

Comment: Start with a small example first. That can be calculated. Afterwards you know a lot more about the problem (_and_ you have a solution, which isn't the best, but a solution nevertheless). Using this knowledge, you will be able to find better algorithms. But the basic calculation is already implemented then. This will keeps your head free.

Comment: Looks like another thing remains unknown - what is the distance the car must travel to reach home?

Comment: You get an input with distances. The example input was: {2 1 1 2} {5 3} {20 2}. This means the distance is 5 between start and the first traffic light, 20 between the first traffic light and the second, and after the last traffic light he is home. Meaning that you can assume that he basically lives at the last traffic light. The distance to home would be 25. These distances differ for each input, so there is no standard distance to home.

Answer (score 0):

An epoch can be characterized by the number of times left you can use your turbo x_t, the remaining distance d_t and t. t modulo the ppcm of all periods would do as well but I don't think you would get much improvement.

From there you can use the A* algorithm ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm)) with the following heuristic:

```
h(d_t, x_t, t) = 
    if (m*x_t <= d_t)
        ceil(d_t/m)
    else 
        ceil((d_t-(x_t*m)) / n)
```

Note that you could be smarter by taking into account the state of the lights. The important things is to never overestimate the optimal cost.
If your heuristic is valid, the algorithm will basically try every possibility while pruning everything that is not as good as the current best solution.

Answer (score 0):

So here is a "dumb, recursive brute force" (as mentioned in comments, however, with a single optimization cutting off sub-optimal branches) solution to the problem in JavaScript (though original tag was Java, that one allows to run the code). Instead of "distance to traffic light" I simply put the absolute position of each light to simplify input processing. Also, starting all the light cycles at time 0 is not as interesting as when each light starts at a specified moment and has unequal activity/inactivity intervals (something like light #1 starts at 1st second, stays active for 3 seconds, then goes off for 5 seconds, then the 3+5 cycle repeats).

```js
"use strict";

class Light {
    constructor(at, interval) {
        this.at = at;
        this.period = interval;
    }
    isRed(time) {
        return Math.floor(time / this.period) % 2 !== 0;
    }
};

class Car {
    constructor(boosts, position = 0, speed = 0, time = 0, prev = null) {
        this.position = position;
        this.speed = speed;
        this.boosts = boosts;
        this.time = time;
        this.prev = prev;
    }
    visits(position) {
        return position >= this.position && position <= this.position + this.speed;
    }
    stop() {
        return new Car(this.boosts, this.position, 0, this.time + 1, this);
    }
    resume(resumeSpeed) {
        const speed = (this.speed === 0) ? resumeSpeed : this.speed;
        return new Car(this.boosts, this.position + speed, speed, this.time + 1, this);
    }
    tryBoost(boostSpeed) {
        return (this.boosts > 0 && this.speed < boostSpeed) ?
            new Car(this.boosts - 1, this.position + boostSpeed, boostSpeed, this.time + 1, this) :
            null;
    }
    withTrace(enabled = false) {
        if (enabled) {
            const trace = [];
            for (var c = this; c !== null; c = c.prev)
                trace.push([c.time, c.position, c.speed]);
            trace.reverse();
            console.log(
                "time :" + trace.map(x => x[0].toLocaleString('en-US', {minimumIntegerDigits: 2})) +
                "\npos  :" + trace.map(x => x[1].toLocaleString('en-US', {minimumIntegerDigits: 2})) +
                "\nspeed:" + trace.map(x => x[2].toLocaleString('en-US', {minimumIntegerDigits: 2})));
        }
        return this;
    }
};

const problem = {
    turboSpeed: 2,
    normalSpeed: 1,
    boosts: 1,
    lights: [
        new Light(5,3),
        new Light(25,2)
    ],
    findRedLight : function (car) {
        return this.lights
            .filter(x => x.isRed(car.time) && car.visits(x.at))[0];
    },
    distance: 0,
    bestTime: Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER,

    findBestTime: function (car) {
        if (car.time > this.bestTime)
            return Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER;

        const distanceLeft = this.distance - car.position;
        if (distanceLeft <= 0)
            return car.withTrace(true).time;
        const scenarios = [];
        const redLight = this.findRedLight(car);
        if (redLight)
            scenarios.push(car.stop());
        else {
            scenarios.push(car.resume(this.normalSpeed));
            const boosted = car.tryBoost(this.turboSpeed);
            if (boosted)
                scenarios.push(boosted);
        }
        const shortestTime = scenarios.map(args => this.findBestTime(args))
            .reduce((a, b) => Math.min(a, b));
        this.bestTime = Math.min(this.bestTime, shortestTime);
        return shortestTime;
    }
};
problem.distance = problem.lights
    .map(x => x.at)
    .reduce((x, y) => Math.max(x, y));

const t = problem.findBestTime(new Car(problem.boosts));
console.log("Best time: " + t);
```